# Using Facebook API to access public group event data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a public website and what I want to do is pretty straightforward, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get everything working right.

I administer an open Facebook group and I want to display the public facebook events of this group on my website.

I can't seem to figure out how to setup my authentication so that I can access the event data. Here is my code for using my application to get an auth token:

```
var fb = new FacebookClientWrapper();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
{
    client_id = AppSettings.AppID,
    client_secret = AppSettings.AppSecret,
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
});
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```

I know this works fine because I can access some information - for example, if I access a specific event by its ID, I can retrieve that information.

The problem occurs when I try to retrieve a list of events with fields within a date range:

```
[HttpGet]
public object GetEventDetails(string unixStartDateTime, string unixEndDateTime)
{
    var parms = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parms.Add("fields", new[] { "id","name","description","start_time","venue" });
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(unixStartDateTime)) { parms.Add("since", unixStartDateTime); }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(unixEndDateTime)) { parms.Add("until", unixEndDateTime); }
    var eventsLink = String.Format(@"/{0}/events", AppSettings.GroupID);
    return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFacebookClient>().Get(eventsLink,parms);
}
```

(I'm aware that even if this did succeed, the return value wouldn't be serializable - I'm not concerned about that quite yet).

This GET request returns the following message:

```
(OAuthException - #102) A user access token is required to request this resource.
```

So the message is quite clear: I need a user access token to get the data I've requested. The question is - what is the best way to do this? Can I give my application a certain permission to read this data? I've looked over all the permissions available to apps, but I don't see one that would do the trick.

I don't want to require people to log onto Facebook to look at public event data, and I love the idea of allowing people with no technical experience to essentially update the website content by posting Facebook events to the group. Right now, I have to duplicate anything they do.

I would think this kind of application would be very common, but no matter what I've read or tried, I can't quite find an example of the same thing that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group/events you need

> A user access token for a member of the group with user_groups permission.

To avoid the hassle, you could create such an Access Token via the Graph Explorer and then store it in your application. Remember to exchange that Access Token to a long-lived one (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending), and that you have to renew the Access Token every 60 days afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. As of yesterday, I requested application access for the user_groups permission, so I am hopeful that, if granted, the application will not need to go through the trouble of getting an access token, exchanging it, and renewing it. If that isn't successful, I think your suggestion is the next best thing. If that is indeed the case, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Alright, I have given up trying to do this the way I originally intended. Your solution would work, but I decided I don't want to run the risk of forgetting to renew the access token and then having my site break. Instead, I have created a JSON file that stores the events and my site will read from that. When a new FB event is created, I will use a token generated by the Graph Explorer to make the api request and save the resulting JSON data to the aforementioned file.